# How to remove the border or border colour of the SearchBar?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am new to Xamarin.forms. I am using a **SearchBar** followed by a **BoxView**.

The problem that I am facing is removing the border line of the SearchBar.

[image]

This border makes the UI appear as if there is a separator in between the SearchBar and the BoxView.

Any help in achieving this is much appreciated.

Thanks much :)

Comment: what platform are you seeing this on? can you include your Xaml

Comment: It looks like the grey separator is your BoxView. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @MarioGalván Its not BoxView's border. Coz, the same border doesn't shown up at the bottom of the BoxView. Its the border of SearchBar only.

Answer (score 0):

Think you might need a custom renderer for this like so:

```
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer( typeof(NamespaceOfApp.MySearchBar), typeof(NamespaceOfApp.iOS.SearchBarWithNoBarRenderer_iOS))]

namespace NamespaceOfApp.iOS
{
    public class SearchBarWithNoBarRenderer_iOS : SearchBarRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged( ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> args )
        {
            base.OnElementChanged( args );

            UISearchBar bar = (UISearchBar)this.Control;
            //set background to empty image
            bar.SetBackgroundImage (new UIImage (), UIBarPosition.TopAttached, UIBarMetrics.Default);
        }
    }
}
```

If you need a hand with custom renderers look [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/introduction/)

Comment: Great!!!! @LainSmith...the suggestion is highly appreciable...but am searching for the solution by not using Renderers. If that is the only option left, I will go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Effects was introduced in Forms v2 as the recommended way to  extending the Forms base controls. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/effects/

For example; this would be your iOS Effect code...

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly:ResolutionGroupName ("MyCompany")]
[assembly:ExportEffect (typeof(FocusEffect), "FocusEffect")]
namespace EffectsDemo.iOS
{
    public class FocusEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached ()
        {
            // your code here        
        }

        protected override void OnDetached ()
        {
            // your code here        
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged (PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged (args);
            // your code here        
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Renderers were the only option in Forms v1.x. Custom Renderers are great for building controls from scratch but it was a bit hit and miss when extending the built-in controls.

Answer (score 0):

Using StoryBoard:

[image]

Using code:

```
public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews ()
        {
            base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews ();
            sampleSearchBar.SearchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal;
            sampleSearchBar.BarTintColor =  UIColor.Clear;

        }
```

Comment: Nice!! @Alvin George.... As of now, am designing UI that will be shared for both iOS and Android. I believe your answer might help me if am using Storyboard and the UI is only for iOS devices.